# Bordered element with display:table extends out of parent

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

This code seems to have a different effect in each browser.

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.box {
    display: table;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

In Chrome 43.0, the table is not confined to the container:

[image: Chrome preview]

In Safari 5.1, the border completely overlaps the table because it seems to interpret the width as inclusive of the border width:

[image: Safari preview]

In Firefox 38.0 and Internet Explorer 11.0, the table renders correctly:

[image: Firefox and Internet Explorer Preview]

The ideal would be that all browsers behave similar to Firefox/Internet Explorer.

Using `box-sizing: border-box` and increasing the width of `.box` to include the width of the border makes all browsers show the Firefox/Internet Explorer version, but assuming that the width of the border is unknown, is there any way to make all major browsers render the model according to Firefox/Internet Explorer (without using JavaScript)?

The following doesn't help at all:

- Using `table-layout: fixed` on the `.box`.
- Using `border-collapse: separate` on the `.box`
- Using `box-sizing: content-box` on the `.box`
- Using `<table>` instead of `display: table` (This just makes Chrome's preview look the same as Safari's and I would prefer to not use a table element.)

<sub>This issue seems to be similar to [Chrome vs. box-sizing:border-box in a display:table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729344/chrome-vs-box-sizingborder-box-in-a-displaytable), but that problem was already fixed.</sub>

---

*Just for frame of reference:*

That was all just a minimal example demonstrating the same problem. The actual issue is that I have a `<div>` with `display: table` that will have its width only defined by the width of its cells (which is equal to the height of the cells) and the padding between them. That div also happens to have a border. That div is contained by another element that is floated to the right. However, because of this problem, when the floated container is completely on the right, the div overflows off the screen.

Comment: Do you have to use display:table on .box?

Comment: @sdcr Yes, it's part of a larger code that has a full table.

Comment: If you fill in some data into the table, it starts to render correctly - http://jsfiddle.net/vy53oaLd/

Comment: @sdcr Oh, that's interesting. However, the cells won't actually have any content in them, and even if I were to use `&nbsp;`, the table cell has a defined width and height to make the width equal the height, which doesn't work out so well when tested: https://jsfiddle.net/vy53oaLd/1/

Comment: @sdcr I added a more specific version of the full problem to the end of the question to hopefully clarify any other concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `box-sizing: border-box` to `.box` and then give it a size to `.box` taking in count it `border-width`

Like this:

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.box {
    display: table;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

The behavior that you have is because `.container` is adjusting to the content of `.box` and the `default value` of `box-sizing` is `content-box` so the border are being left out.

**Added another solution because the above solution requires the border width to be known beforehand**

Trying set `display: table-cell` to the content inside of `.box`

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.box {
    display: table;
    border: 5px solid blue;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution motivated me to combine the two methods, which produces the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the .container : width: 20px

Comment: True, but I need a code that assumes the width of the border of the inner element is unknown (and the inner width of the element, if possible).